# Is the mind a product of maya?

Tags: brahman, atma, maya, mind

A pure soul is considered to be the same as the Supreme Soul,i.e Brahman.As per my knowledge,I know that the soul consists of:

1.Mind

2.Intelligence(Buddhi)

3.Ego(Ahankar)

If a pure soul merges with the Supreme Soul,does that mean that the soul loses its identity and therefore stops thinking?If thats the case,maybe we can assume that the mind exists only in the realms of maya and therefore be a product of maya.

Also,when a soul merges with the Supreme One,does that mean that it is ego-less and therefore stops acting on its own?

Comment: Yes, mind is the product of maya. In fact, everything is the product of Maya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** only when it is one (or connected) with the Supreme soul or the Consciousness, it can create everything and anything, including all the Tattvas, and which include the mind etc ..

> **This Âtman again, united with Mâyâ**, composed of desires and Karmas,
>   wants to create, due to the want of discrimination, the twenty-four
>   tattvas, according to the previous Samskâras (tendencies), time and
>   Karma.
>
> **Mâyâ united with Chaitanya (Intelligence), i. e., Chidâbhâsa is the efficient cause of this Universe; whereas Mâyâ reduced to and united
>   with five original elements is the material Cause of the Universe.**
>   Some call this Mâyâ tapas; some call Her inert, material; some call
>   Her knowledge; some call Her Mâyâ, Pradhâna, Prakriti, Ajâ (unborn)
>   and some others call Her S'aktî....................
>
> Mâyâ S'abala (divided into various parts) and so forth. In all the
>   S'âstras, it is stated to be the Cause of all causes, the Primeval
>   Tattva and Sachchidânanda Vigraha. Where all the Karmas are solidified
>   and where Ichchâ S'aktî (will), Jñâna S'aktî (intelligence) and Kriyâ
>   S'aktî (action) all are melted in one, that is called the Mantra Hrîm,
>   that is the first Tattva. From this comes out Âkâsa, having the
>   property of sound, thence Vâyu (air) with "touch" property; then fire
>   with form, then water having "Rasa" property; and lastly the earth
>   having the quality "smell." The Pundits say that the "sound" is the
>   only quality of Âkâsa; air has two qualities viz., sound and touch,
>   fire has three qualities sound, touch, form; water has four qualities
>   sound, touch, form, taste; and the earth has five qualities sound,
>   touch, form, taste and smell. Out of these five original elements, the
>   allpervading, Sûtra (string or thread) arose. This Sûtrâtman (soul) is
>   called the "Linga Deha," comprising within itself all the Prânas; this
>   is the subtle body of the Paramâtman. And what is said in the previous
>   lines as Avyakta or Unmanifested and in which the Seed of the World is
>   involved and whence the Linga Deha has sprung, that is called the
>   Causal body (Kârana body) of the Paramâtman. The five original
>   elements (Apañchikrita called the five Tan Mâtrâs) being created, next
>   by the Pañchîkarana process, the gross elements are created. The
>   process is now being stated :-- O Girijâ! Each of the five original
>   elements is divided into two parts; one part of each of which is
>   subdivided into four parts. This fourth part of each is united with
>   the half of four other elements different from it and thus each gross
>   element is formed. By these five gross elements, the Cosmic (Virât)
>   body is formed and this is called the Gross Body of the God.
>   Jñânendriyas (the organs of knowledge) arise from Sattva Gunas of each
>   of these five elements. Again the Sattva Gunas of each of the
>   Jñânendriyas united become the Antah Karanâni. This Antah karana is of
>   four kinds, according as its functions vary. **When it is engaged in
>   forming Sankalpas, resolves, and Vikalpas (doubts) it is called
>   "mind." When it is free from doubts and when it arrives at the
>   decisive conclusion, it is called "Chitta";** and when it rests simply
>   on itself in the shape of the feeling "I", it is called Ahamkâra. From
>   the Rajo Guna of each of the five elements arises Vâk (speech), Pâni
>   (hands) Pâda (feet), Pâyu (Anus) and Upastha (organs of generation).
>   Again their Rajo parts united give rise to the five Prânas (Prâna,
>   Apâna, Samâna, Udâna and Vyâna) the Prâna Vayu resides in the heart;
>   Apâna Vayu in the Arms; Samâna Vayu resides in the Navel; Udâna Vayu
>   rasides in the Throat; and the Vyâna Vâyu resides, pervading all over
>   the body. My subtle body (Linga Deha) arises from the union of the
>   five Jñânendriyas, the five Karmendriyas (organs of action), the five
>   Pranas and the mind and Buddhi, these seventeen elements. And the
>   Prakriti that resides there is divided into two parts; one is pure
>   (Suddha Sattva) Mâyâ and the other is the impure Mâyâ or Avidyâ united
>   with the Gunas. By Mâyâ is meant She, who, without concealing Her
>   refugees, protects them. When the Supreme Self is reflected on this
>   S'uddha Sattva, Mâyâ, He is called Îs'vara.

[**From the Devi BhAgavata PurAna's Book 7, Chapter 32.**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam38.htm)